# RegEx for expression between 2 white space characters

Tags: regex

I have a file directory listing from an embedded target that looks like this:

```
Directory of D:\
D                   0     19-Jan-15 16:12:16     FILE1
D                   0     19-Jan-15 16:09:31     FILE2
D                   0     21-Jan-15 14:10:33     FILE3
94951/218985 MB unused/total
```

And I am looking to only get the file names. The string in c# will look like this:

```
\r\nDirectory of D:\\\r\nD     \t         0\t19-Jan-15 16:12:16\tFILE1\r\nD     \t         0\t19-Jan-15 16:09:31\tFILE2\r\nD     \t         0\t21-Jan-15 14:04:15\tFILE3\r\n94969/218985 MB unused/total\r\n
```

I noticed that the file names are always contained between a `\t` and a `\r\n` so i thought the easiest way to approach it would be with `\t(.*?)\r\n` But this will get the whole line. What is the best way to combine this with a regex to omit the first 2 `\t` in the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because file names cannot include tab characters, you can replace the `.` in `\t(.*?)\r\n` with `[^\t]`. Also, you can use lookarounds to not match the `\t` at the start and the `\r` at the end, eliminate the unnecessary capturing group, and change `*?` to `+`:

```
(?<=\t)[^\t]+(?=\r)
```

This regex will match a sequence of characters that does not include any tab characters, as long as the sequence is between a tab (`\t`) and a carriage return (`\r`).

You can find an online explanation and demonstration [here](https://regex101.com/r/nF3tD7/2). Note that to work on regex101, I had to change the `\r` to a `\n`; you will most likely still need the `\r` in your regex.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex:

```
\t([^\t]*)\r\n
```

i.e. find all characters non tab characters between `\t` and `\r\n` thus giving you file names in each line.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hM1cE3/1)

Comment: Under c# this doesnt work as expected, it includes the post text `94951/218985 MB unused/total` in the final file name. I am using the `Regex.Split` command, can you see a reason why this would happen?

Comment: Just after writing that i relised i probably should be using `Regex.matches`

Comment: Yes that's right, this regex is meant for `Regex.matches`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a capturing group or like this:

```
 (?<=\t)[^\t]+(?=[\r\n])
```